# Comparing Float value in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, floating-point, hibernate-criteria

I have a column called "Percentage", which is a float, in my database and I'm trying to get all the rows who's Percentage is 0. But I'm getting the error below.

```
public List<DataFromDB> getDatafromDB(){
Criteria cr = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(DataFromDB.class);
cr.add(Restriction.eq("Percentage",0));
return cr.list();
}
```

Error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

Comment: Try this: `Restriction.eq("Percentage", 0F)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be using 0f to indicate float. 0 is an integer.

```
public List<DataFromDB> getDatafromDB(){
    Criteria cr = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(DataFromDB.class);
    cr.add(Restriction.eq("Percentage",0f));
    return cr.list();
}
```

Comment: note: similarly for long, you should use 0L instead of 0

Answer (score 2):

Use `cr.add(Restriction.eq("Percentage",0F));`